# Android: iosched clone resource/api issue

Tags: android, ant, actionbarsherlock, android-library, iosched

I am using Ant to compile a clone of iosched but am running into an error. Lots, actually, but I'm sure it's from something simple I'm not seeing.

When running `ant debug` when aapt is bundling resources:
`[aapt] C:\DEV\IOSCHED\android\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog'.`

And lots of similar errors. I've been told this is a build target error, but the `abs` library `project.properties` and AndroidManifest are both targeting API15. (minTarget 7, as default). I've done `ant clean` already.

Any ideas? And more specifically, can someone more familiar with aapt or the android compilation process tell me what's happened here?

Answer (score 0):

For quick solution, you can just clone from eclipse ported version iosched 2013 here :

https://github.com/yodiaditya/iosched-2013-eclipse